# Scrapy: How to get a list of urls and loop over them afterwards

Tags: scrapy

i'm new to python and scrapy, watched a few udemy and youtube tutorials and now trying my first own example. I know howto loop, if there's a next-button. But in my case, there is none.

Here's my code, working on one of the urls, but the start url needs to be changed later:

```
class Heroes1JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'heroes1_job'

# where to extract
allowed_domains = ['icy-veins.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/alarak-build-guide']

def parse(self, response):
    #what to extract
    hero_names = response.xpath('//span[@class="page_breadcrumbs_item"]/text()').extract()
    hero_buildss = response.xpath('//h3[@class="toc_no_parsing"]/text()').extract()
    hero_buildskillss = response.xpath('//span[@class="heroes_build_talent_tier_visual"]').extract()

    for item in zip(hero_names, hero_buildss, hero_buildskillss):
        new_item = Heroes1Item()

        new_item['hero_name'] = item[0]
        new_item['hero_builds'] = item[1]
        new_item['hero_buildskills'] = item[2]


        yield new_item
```

But this is only one Hero, and i want about 90 of them. Each url depends on the hero name.
I can get the list of urls by this command:

```
    start_urls = ['https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/assassin-hero-guides')

    ...

  response.xpath('//div[@class="nav_content_block_entry_heroes_hero"]/a/@href').extract()
```

But i don´t know howto store this list in order to get the parse function to loop over them.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it critical to parse them in `parse` function? You can parse your hero list in one function and then iterate this list to scrape hero data it in this way:

```
from scrapy import Request
...

start_urls = ['https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/assassin-hero-guides')

def parse(self, response):
    heroes_xpath = '//div[@class="nav_content_block_entry_heroes_hero"]/a/@href'
    for link in response.xpath(heroes_xpath).extract():
        yield Request(response.urljoin(link), self.parse_hero)

def parse_hero(self, response):
    # copying your method here
    hero_names = response.xpath('//span[@class="page_breadcrumbs_item"]/text()').extract()
    hero_buildss = response.xpath('//h3[@class="toc_no_parsing"]/text()').extract()
    hero_buildskillss = response.xpath('//span[@class="heroes_build_talent_tier_visual"]').extract()

    for item in zip(hero_names, hero_buildss, hero_buildskillss):
        new_item = Heroes1Item()
        new_item['hero_name'] = item[0]
        new_item['hero_builds'] = item[1]
        new_item['hero_buildskills'] = item[2]
        yield new_item
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I think i understand your strategy :)
Sadly, it returns an error and i hope you have one more idea:

Comment: ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/assassin-hero-guides> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: Heroes1JobSpider.parse callback is not defined

Comment: Please, check the indents in your class, that `parse` function is inside your class. Because this error means that problem is not in my code.

Comment: You´re completely right! I pressed tab several times and now everything is fine. Thank you very much!